# cloudflare worker can't forward some of my post requests

Tags: cloudflare

I wrote a cloudflare worker to check headers for authorization. If it is missing, just forward the requests. I found most requests are ok, but some post requests throws errors like this:

```
  "exceptions": [
    {
      "name": "TypeError",
      "message": "Cannot reconstruct a Request with a used body.",
      "timestamp": 1688611154771
    }
  ],
  "logs": [
   {
      "message": [
      "forwarded: https://..."
       ],
      "level": "log",
      "timestamp": 1688611154771
   }
 ]
```

And the code throws exception is like this:

```
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    // let error pass to the origin server
    ctx.passThroughOnException();

    let fwd_request = new Request(request);
    const headers = request.headers;
    const auth = headers.get('Authorization')
    if (!auth) {       
     console.log(`forwarded: ${request.url}`)
     return fetch(request);
    }
    ...
```

So, the console.log is printed out, and **fetch(request)** doesn't change the original request.

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
let fwd_request = new Request(request);
```

consumes the original `request`'s body, and transfers it to `fwd_request`. If you try to do `fetch(request)` after this, and it has a body, it won't work. You could do `fetch(fwd_request)` instead, or you could delay constructing `fwd_request` until after the `if (!auth)` block, since it looks like you don't use it before that block anyway.

```
export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    // let error pass to the origin server
    ctx.passThroughOnException();

    const headers = request.headers;
    const auth = headers.get('Authorization')
    if (!auth) {       
     console.log(`forwarded: ${request.url}`)
     return fetch(request);
    }
    let fwd_request = new Request(request);
    ...
```

Comment: thx. i figured. i thought it's just a clone, and won't change the original request.